# ArcGIS Dissolve equivalent in R

Tags: r, aggregate, polygon

I am trying to convert some ArcGIS work into an R-script.
I have a shapefile that has 2 variables, one is the FRU(an ID field representing different region names 1 through 60) and a geometry variable (I assume this is showing where these features are located spatially).

What I want is to create a new shapefile that combines the geometry for FRU=o, FRU=1, FRU=2...FRU=60.

So instead of having 26, 967 rows, I have 61 rows.

Comment: Have you seen this discussion? https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/290

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is generally good practice to include a reproducible code example with your questions so it is easier for others to help solve the problem. You can pass your data into the `dput` function in R to get a copy and pasteable version of your data.

For this problem, I would suggest using the `sf` package:

```
# Read example data from sf package
nc <-  sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# add a dummy column do dissolve with
nc <- dplyr::mutate(nc, example = c(rep('a', 50), rep('b', 50)))

# group the data by the new column
nc <- dplyr::group_by(nc, example)

# summarize the data
nc <- dplyr::summarise(nc)
```

Using your example, you would instead say `my_data <- dplyr::group_by(my_data, FRU)` and then use the same summarise function `dplyr::summarise(my_data)`.

Comment: Beat me to it! nice answer

Comment: Thank you ColinB, I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my Q. When I run the first line: # Read example data from sf package
nc <-  sf::st_read(system.file("FRU.shp", package="sf")), I get an error message saying: Error: 'dsn' must point to a source, not an empty string - Do you know what this means? Thank you!

Comment: I am also getting another error when I run the line: nc_dissolve<-nc%>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(). It says Error in CPL_geos_union(st_geometry(x), by_feature, is_coverage): evaluation error: TopologyException: side location conflict at -1312 249 1266000

Comment: Make sure you are pointing `st_read()` to where FRU.shp is located. Try using the full path like this `st_read("C:/gis/FRU.shp")`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the `sf` package is the premiere tool for working with spatial data in R. However, there is no dedicated `sf::st_dissolve()`.

Instead you can simply define a grouping variable in your data and use `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarize`.  The example is simplified version of examples here (https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/290).

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# Example data
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# Dummy grouping variable
nc$group <- factor(rep(1:3, length.out = nrow(nc)))

# Dissolve
nc_dissolve <- nc %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize()

# Plot results
ggplot(data = nc_dissolve) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = group))
```

[image]